# OBSOLETE - Mobile Exchange Library for .NET Compact Framework

Tags: library, obsolete, c#

> ### Obsolete:  This library was made for a decommissioned version of the API. Also, the source code is no longer available.

[image: mobileexchange]

### About

Since the .NET Compact Framework is always lagging behind in terms of what is implemented, and what is not implemented, I made a .NET library for the Stack Exchange API specifically made for the .NET Compact Framework v3.5.

### Code Snippet

The API is kept at its simplest form, with a unique static class entry point, returning results containing simple data types matching the JSON responses.

```
// Sync calls
TagsResult result = StackExchangeHelper.GetPopularTags( page );

foreach( Tag tag in result.Tags )
{
  //...
}

// Async calls
StackExchangeHelper.GetStatsAsync( 
  new ResultCallback<StatsResult>( this.OnGetStatsCompleted ), 
  null );

private void OnGetStatsCompleted( StatsResult result, object state )
{
  foreach( Tag tag in result.Tags )
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

As you can see, the async pattern does not use IAsyncResult return values. Since mobile devices should avoid many concurrent requests, the abort system is centralized.

```
ServiceHelper.AbortAll();
```

#### License

The license is [MS-PL](http://mobileexchange.codeplex.com/license).

#### Download

The sources are DEAD LINK <del>[available on CodePlex](http://mobileexchange.codeplex.com)</del>. There is no official release for the moment.

#### Platform

Though this library should work on any .NET Framework, it specifically targets .NET Compact Framework 3.5. Let's call this a new library for a legacy framework. :)

### Contact

You can reach me on Twitter at [@martinplante](http://twitter.com/martinplante).

### Code

This library is made in C#, using .NET CF 3.5, the excellent [JSON.NET library](http://json.codeplex.com), and a closed-source control library made for slimCODE products.

Comment: Awesome logo. Please, Jeff, let him keep it!